# Oracle Apex - 'Your session has ended' message after saving a change

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am encountering an absurd situation when using Oracle Apex. When I log into my apllication, select a page from the list of pages and click the Play button (save and run page) I get a normal output in a new tab showing me the page.

The problem starts when I decide to change the page or any of the pages from the list. After making a change I am unable to save it. I get a message: Your session has ended. If I want to save the change I have to reload the page, log into Apex again, select the desired page and make the change.

It is totally weird, because before today this did not happen and Apex was able to save changes and run the page without having to log into again.

I tried to configure session timeout or google this, but nothing helped. I will appreciate every suggestion.

Comment: which version of ORDS,  APEX and Oracle DB are you using ? There are bugs related to it, therefore it would be good if you can provide such information

Answer (score 0):

If your application hasn't changed and the data hasn't changed, the only answer could be that the platform changed. Have you restored your application from a recent backup and confirmed that the issue still happens? If so, check system settings.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issue with Oracle Live SQL. I couldn't find an explanation of the differences, but they seem to use a very similar interface and login system (my account works both places).

The issue seemed to be my cookies. Here's how to delete (in Edge):

1. Click the 'lock' icon -> Cookies

[image: Edge lock dialog]

2. Select `livesql.oracle.com` -> Delete

[image: Delete]